# Can switching from .com TLD to non .com TLD affect emails even if MX records migrated correctly

Tags: top-level-domains, mx

I have a high-level question about a customer that switched from a .com TLD to a .fun TLD. They didn't switch hosting, only their TLD. They're now having issues with their emails, personal and campaign based, being blocked.

Before I dig in to the technical stuff, I wanted to know if anyone had a similar issue. Before I dig in to MX records and such, I didn't know if there were known TLD issues with ones like .fun, etc.
Sorry if this is a vague question. And I promise I've been googling and asking first!

Comment: Define "being blocked"? Ask any sender of email to their new domain to share what error it gets back or email delivery notification for the mail not going through and depending on that it might explain where the problem is.

Comment: Also technically, this website is for questions about running a website, so email stuff is a tad offtopic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New domains often need to build up trust with the major email services which will have an impact on campaigns. Once all your settings are up you should work on sending a few smaller campaigns to known good addresses with those services that don't bounce, etc.

It's possible that the MX records are fine, but have you checked the SPF and DKIM records? These can also have a significant impact on delivery success.

Are they sending the emails themselves or using a third party campaign system? Often they use delegated name servers for a sub-domain.

Comment: I did check those. Can two TLD's share SPF and DKIM records or would that create the issue. Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @Tonkadog You can have the same SPF records on both TLDs as these can be fairly open/flexible (they can refer to the current domain without specifying it). Technically I think your DKIM can be shared if the public key is valid for both domains.